# JS regex: unable to return array matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I Have a form with multiple input text like:

```
<div class="width-height">
    <input value="" name="items[1][width]" type="text">
    <br>
    <input value="" name="items[1][height]" type="text">
</div>
 <div class="width-height">
    <input value="" name="items[2][width]" type="text">
    <br>
    <input value="" name="items[2][height]" type="text">
</div>
```

I try to get with a JS foreach "number" and "width" or "height" in an array

the best result possibility should be an array with 2 value in `console.log`:

```
1,width
1,height
2,width
2,height
```

I try 2 regex :

```
// first: /\d\]\[[a-z]+/i
// second: /\d\]\[\w+/g
$('.width-height > input').each(function () {
    console.log("1 : " + $(this).attr('name').match(/\d\]\[[a-z]+/i));
    console.log("2 : " +  $(this).attr('name').match(/\d\]\[\w+/g));
});
```

but the result is only:

```
1 : 1][width
2 : 1][width
```

I have tried to use uncapture setting for excluding part that I don't need :

```
console.log("3 : " +  $(this).attr('name').match(/(?:\w+\[)\d(?:\]\[)\w+/g));
```

but it return only 1 string

```
3 : items[1][width
```

I guess I don't understand something in regex.. with non-capture and "g" flag i think it should return all possibility without capture and build an array with retrieving value but .. not.. :-/

Tranks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-capturing group doesn't exclude any data from the whole match, it just won't appear in the list of captured groups.

You need to use capturing groups to handle this (which also means you can't use `match`).

A capturing group is delimited with `(` and `)`.

```
$('.width-height > input').each(function () {
    var regex = /(\d)\]\[(\w+)/;
    var matches = regex.exec($(this).attr('name'));
    console.log(matches[1] + "," + matches[2]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this straight-forward, native approach:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('div.width-height > input[name^="items"]');
var result = [];
var match = null;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs,function(input){
    match = input.name.match(/^items\[(\d)\]\[(width|height)\]$/);
    if(match.length===3)
        result.push([match[1],match[2]]);
});

console.log( result );
```

Did you mean an array of arrays by “array with 2 value”? If the format of the `name` attribute value isn’t that static, it would be just a minor change in the regex. Or did you wish to have your regex explained?

Comment: I just want to handle both value, he can override, its just because I need to do a function if its "width" and another with "height" and I need the number to passed through the function. That I see.. its just the non "g" flag .. its works as well

Comment: @Jean-philippeEmond: I don’t entirely understand. You need the number and the word, right? The “global” flag is irrelevant because there is no repetition in a single attribute so the first match suffices.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.width-height > input').each(function () {
    var matches = $(this).attr('name').match(/[\d]?[\w]+/gi);     
    console.log(matches.splice(1));   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in doing this without jQuery, this will return to you an array of your requested output.

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
var result = Array.prototype.slice.call(inputs).map(function(el){
   return el.getAttribute("name").replace(/.*\[(\d+)\]\[(\w+)\].*$/, "$1,$2");                                      
});
console.log(result);
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/modipojovi/edit?html,js,output)

[REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/jM8wS6/1)